# How to move a Poly3DCollection object in matplotlib?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I try to make an animation using matplotlib and fail at the first step. I cannot even make a moving cube. I created six surface by using the `plot_surface` method but I cant move them precisely. I have two questions:

1. How to move a Poly3DCollection object.

   The method I tried is using `set_offsets` provided by the collection class.
   But this method can only set `x` and `y` and the unit is weird.
   For example, I create a cube at (1, 0 ,0) and invoke set_offsets([100, 0]),
   the horizontal position of the plotted cube is approximately 1.4. I try to link this unit to the dpi of the figure object but failed.
2. What are the units for my data, the line width, and the `set_offsets` method.

My current code is as follows:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')

    class cube():

      def __init__(self, ax, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0,
        height = 1., width = 1., depth = 1.) :

        self.ax = ax
        self.initiate(ax, x, y, z, height, width, depth)

      def initiate(self, ax, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0,
        height = 1., width = 1., depth = 1.) :

        self.ax = ax
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z
        self.height, self.width, self.depth = height, width, depth

        X = [[x, x + width], [x, x + width]]
        Y = [[y, y], [y, y]]
        Z = [[z, z], [depth, depth]]
        self.top = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1, edgecolors='black', shade=False, color = 'red')

        X = [[x, x + width], [x, x + width]]
        Y = [[y + height, y + height], [y + height, y + height]]
        Z = [[z, z], [depth, depth]]
        self.bottom = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1, edgecolors='black', shade=False, color = 'red')

        X = [[x, x + width], [x, x + width]]
        Y = [[y, y], [y + height, y + height]]
        Z = [[z, z], [z, z]]
        self.front = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1, edgecolors='black', shade=False, color = 'green')

        X = [[x, x + width], [x, x + width]]
        Y = [[y, y], [y + height, y + height]]
        Z = [[depth, depth], [depth, depth]]
        self.back = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1, edgecolors='black', shade=False, color = 'green')

        X = [[x, x], [x, x]]
        Y = [[y, y + height], [y, y + height]]
        Z = [[z, z], [depth, depth]]
        self.left = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1, edgecolors='black', shade=False, color = 'blue')

        X = [[x + width, x + width], [x + width, x + width]]
        Y = [[y, y + height], [y, y + height]]
        Z = [[z, z], [depth, depth]]
        self.right = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,
          linewidth=1, edgecolors='black', shade=False, color = 'blue')

      def set_location(self, x, y, z) :
        c.front.set_offsets([x, y])
        c.back.set_offsets([x, y])
        c.left.set_offsets([x, y])
        c.right.set_offsets([x, y])
        c.top.set_offsets([x, y])
        c.bottom.set_offsets([x, y])

    c = cube(ax, 1, 0, 0)
    print type(c.left)
    c.set_location(100, 0, 0)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PolyCollection documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection), the offsets are applied in screen coordinates by default. To move your objects in data coordinates, first call `set_offset_position('data')` for each of your objects, e.g.

```
self.top.set_offset_position('data')
```